# Populate datagridview with click event

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to load a datagridview on a click event (Like a search button). I am not getting any errors during the process but my datagridview isn't populating. I know the method to open my db connection works, and that my SQL statement also works as I've tested it in Access, and I believe it would bomb out if it were the SQL statement anyway. I think it's in the event declaration, but I'm very new to vb. My code is below:

```
Private Sub btnQuickSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnQuickSearch.Click
    dgvQuickSearchEmployee.Visible = True
    qSearchEmployee()

End Sub

Private Sub qSearchEmployee()
    conOpen()
    Dim qSearchString As String
    qSearchString = tbQuickSearch.Text
    qSearchString = qSearchString.ToUpper()



    sqlStr = "SELECT employeeID, firstName, lastName, department FROM [employee] WHERE (employeeID LIKE '*" & qSearchString & "*' OR firstName LIKE '*" & qSearchString & "*' OR lastName LIKE '*" & qSearchString & "*' OR department LIKE '*" & qSearchString & "*') AND active = TRUE"


    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim daEmployee As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, con)
    daEmployee.Fill(dt)
    dgvQuickSearchEmployee.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
    dgvQuickSearchEmployee.Refresh()

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE!
Here is the way my code looks now(Not much different). It is now populating the datagridview, but it's not returning any results at all, no matter what I do with the search.

```
Private Sub btnQuickSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnQuickSearch.Click
    dgvQuickSearchEmployee.Visible = True
    qSearchEmployee()

End Sub

Private Sub qSearchEmployee()
    conOpen()
    Dim qSearchString As String
    qSearchString = tbQuickSearch.Text
    qSearchString = qSearchString.ToUpper()

    sqlStr = "SELECT employeeID, firstName, lastName, department FROM [employee] WHERE (employeeID LIKE '*" & qSearchString & "*' OR firstName LIKE '*" & qSearchString & "*' OR lastName LIKE '*" & qSearchString & "*' OR department LIKE '*" & qSearchString & "*') AND active = TRUE"

    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, con)
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgvQuickSearchEmployee.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
    dgvQuickSearchEmployee.Refresh()

End Sub
```

Comment: have you change dgvQuickSearchEmployee.DataSource = dt.DefaultView to dgvQuickSearchEmployee.DataSource = dt

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
'Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet    'Not required or Not inused
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
'ds.Tables.Add(dt)          'Not required or Not inused
Dim daEmployee As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, con)
daEmployee.Fill(dt)
dgvQuickSearchEmployee.DataSource = dt
dgvQuickSearchEmployee.Refresh()
```

Comment: Did not work, but thanks! I should have put an update in though, it looks now like it's populating, but it won't return any results

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dgvQuickSearchEmployee.Refresh()` try `dgvQuickSearchEmployee.Databind()`

Comment: While this might provide a solution, try to elaborate on what you suggest and why it might be a solution. As is, this is a poor answer.